# Automatically set selected keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, import, keyboard-shortcuts

Visual Studio permits [exporting and importing shortcut keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx). However, it appears to be all or nothing.

I want to distribute a file to other developers that they can use to set particular shortcuts **without losing all of their existing custom shortcuts.**

If I use the Import and Export Settings Wizard and edit the .vssettings file to (for example) reduce the UserShortcuts section to the following:

```
<UserShortcuts>
    <Shortcut Command="View.ObjectBrowser" Scope="Global">Alt+=</Shortcut>
</UserShortcuts>
```

Importing this works, but wipes out all other custom shortcuts.

The *best* case would be if I could:

- add new shortcuts
- remove *conflicting* existing shortcuts
- preserve all other shortcuts (custom or default)
- in both VS 2012 and 2010
- without spending days developing a custom solution.

Can this be done, and if so, how?